# calling service with pkcs#12 on azure

Tags: c#, azure, ssl, certificate

I received a P12 certificate that I need to use to call a webservice from a Azure worker role. I uploaded the certificate, I turned it into a pem file and added it programmaticaly, but I Always get the exception on GetRequest:

```
The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
```

I know the p12 contains also a private key, so that might be the issue...

```
String strPem = "***valid PEM in BAS64***";
Uri uriGateway = new Uri("https://xxxx");
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uriGateway);
byte[] baPem = Convert.FromBase64String(strPem);
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AcceptAllCertifications);
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(baPem);
request.Method = "GET";
request.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: Where did you upload the certificate and in which format? It should be uploaded under management certificates section and should be in cer file format.

Comment: I uploaded it in Cloud Services > Certificates in the Azure Management Portal. I uploaded it as a pfx.
If I convert it to a cer, it looses the private key, from what I understood... (and this is likely the issue).
Note that I tried the certificate both in the azure management portal and in the code via the PEM. Both cases do not work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

Create a x509Certificate and use the Import method to import the p12 certicate file.

```
var certificateFileName = Server.MapPath("~/Cert/cert.pfx");
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2();
cert.Import(certificateFileName,"pw",X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);
```

And now it works...